# Functions to convert camelCase strings to snake_case

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x

I have written two functions, one actual and one helper, to convert camelCase strings into snake_case strings (I call it joint-lower case). Any ideas for improvement are welcome.

```
def _cc2jl(string):
    """Camel case to joint-lower helper."""

    for index, current in enumerate(string):

        if is_upper(current):
            if index > 0:
                previous = string[index-1]

                if is_upper(previous):
                    try:
                        next = string[index+1]
                    except IndexError:
                        yield current.lower()
                        continue
                    else:
                        if is_upper(next):
                            yield current.lower()
                            continue

                yield '_' + current.lower()
                continue

            yield current.lower()
            continue

        yield current


def cc2jl(string):
    """Converts a camel case string to joint-lower."""

    return ''.join(_cc2jl(string))
```

Expected behaviour:

```
>>> cc2jl('m')
'm'
>>> cc2jl('AA')
'aa'
>>> cc2jl('MySQLDatabase')
'my_sql_database'
>>> cc2jl('GarbageCollection')
'garbage_collection'
>>> cc2jl('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think regex would be the easiest to do this with. You just need to find each word in the string.

1. The name starts with an uppercase letter. `[A-Z]`. However due to the way the rest of the regex works, we can change this to `.`, so that we match all words, even ones that start with `_`.
2. The word will either contain uppercase or lowercase letters, both with other characters - excluding `_`.

   - Uppercase:

     1. The word won't be lowercase or have a `_`. `[^a-z_]+`
     2. You don't want the last uppercase letter or a `_`. `(?=[A-Z_])`
     3. You want the above if it's the last in the string. `(?=[A-Z_]|$)`
   - Lowercase:

     1. The word won't be uppercase or have a `_`. `[^A-Z_]+`

And so you can use:

```
(.(?:[^a-z_]+(?=[A-Z_]|$)|[^A-Z_]+))
```

You then want to apply the following to these:

1. Prepend the name with a single `_`, unless:

   - It's the first word in the name
   - The word already starts with a `_`
2. Convert the word to lowercase

Making:

```
def _jl_match(match):
    group = match.group()
    prefix = bool(match.start() and not group.startswith('_'))
    return '_' * prefix + group.lower()
```

And so I'd use:

```
def _jl_match(match):
    group = match.group()
    prefix = bool(match.start() and not group.startswith('_'))
    return '_' * prefix + group.lower()

REGEX = r'(.(?:[^a-z_]+(?=[A-Z_]|$)|[^A-Z_]+))'

def _cc2jl(string):
    return re.subn(REGEX, _jl_match, string)[0]
```

Comment: Nice, I knew there should be a way to do it with a single regex, but my regex-fu was too weak to come up with one...I added your function to the timing plot, and it is the fastest (so far). I did modify it so that the regex is compiled first.

Comment: Here is a [comparison of various regexes that could be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29916065/1157100).

Comment: I went with your solution because of its simplicity and performance: https://github.com/HOMEINFO/strflib/commit/de55f543cc6d7ef49daf1e73637e24829525811e

Comment: @Graipher Thank you, I'm honestly surprised it's the fastest, I thought the function calls would kill it.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thank you. But, you should be made aware that you violated CC-BY-SA by relicensing the above code to GPL. I don't mind, however some people may and could proceed with legal action. Just be a bit more careful about licensing, :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz thanks for the hint. I'm glad that you don't mind. Regarding the BY-part, this is why I added the `__credits__`. ;)

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thank you for that. But it wasn't the BY part you violated - and I'm happy you didn't :) It was the SA part. If SE used CC-BY-SA 4.0 and you relicensed to GPLv3, then there wouldn't be any violation. but they use CC-BY-SA 3.0, ):

Comment: @Peilonrayz according to [this list](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses) one is allowed to relicense CC-BY-SA 3.0 with a later version of BY-SA, e.g. BY-SA 4.0. The latter one can be, as you already stated be relicensed under GPLv3, which I did. IANAL, but I think, it may just okay to implicitely do the 3.0→4.0 transition.

Comment: @RichardNeumann That's a good point. I wonder if you can do that... IANAL too, so I guess it's time to go to Law.SE, ;P

Comment: An update on your solution: It did not cover the case of a string `^[A-Z]$` or `[a-z][A-Z]$`. So I added a little question mark: `r'(.?(?:[^a-z_]+(?=[A-Z_]|$)|[^A-Z_]+))'`

Comment: @Peilonrayz I think [opensource.se] might be a better fit.

Comment: @RichardNeumann [Here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/226/6130) is the question; your answer is provided but hasn't many votes.

Answer (score 16):

### A couple of things:

1. Why 2 functions?
2. Now that we established (1), you can get rid of the `yield`s. 
   *`yield` is useful when you want to process stuff **in chunks** and do not want to wait for the entire population to be created first. This is not the case here.*
3. There are some `continue`s that do make sense and some that are redundant. Yours are of the latter type.
4. Nested `if` statements without corresponding `else` clauses can be merged with `and` if readability is not reduced.

### Putting all that together, we get the following:

```
def cc2jl(my_str):
  """Camel case to joint-lower"""

  r = my_str[0].lower()
  for i, letter in enumerate(my_str[1:], 1):
    if letter.isupper():
      try:
        if my_str[i-1].islower() or my_str[i+1].islower():
          r += '_'
      except IndexError:
        pass
    r += letter.lower()
  return r

print(cc2jl('m'))                  #-> m
print(cc2jl('AA'))                 #-> aa
print(cc2jl('MySQLDatabase'))      #-> my_sql_database
print(cc2jl('GarbageCollection'))  #-> garbage_collection
print(cc2jl('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'))  #-> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

---

Finally, some thoughts on avoiding the `try` block that *bothers me personally.*

We can leverage from the [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) used in Python's logical expressions and (re-)write the following:

```
def cc2jl(my_str):
  """Camel case to joint-lower"""

  r = my_str[0].lower()
  for i, letter in enumerate(my_str[1:], 1):
    if letter.isupper():
      if my_str[i-1].islower() or (i != len(my_str)-1 and my_str[i+1].islower()):
        r += '_'
    r += letter.lower()
  return r
```

Note the `i != len(my_str)-1` on the **left** side of the **`and`**. If this returns `False` the `my_str[i+1]` is not evaluated at all and thus cannot `raise` the `IndexError`.

Comment: Nice job cleaning up OP's code! I added your function to the timing plot in my answer, it is faster than my regex function and the OP's function (probably due to getting rid of the overhead of the generator).

Comment: @Graipher The thing that I do not like the most about my approach is the `try-except` block but couldn't think of something more elegant.

Comment: You could replace it with `if not 0 < i < len(my_str) - 1`, but I'm not sure that is any better, because it needs to check it every iteration, instead of only failing at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: @Graipher the `0` I do not need since I am iterating over `my_str[1:]`.I tried going over `my_str[1:-1]` instead and handling the last letter in the `return` line but that wasn't any better either. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

First a note on naming: `cc2jl` is a very cryptic name. Give the public function a clearer name, like `to_snake_case` or something similar (note that the function does not do anything to a string that already *is* in `snake_case`).

---

While I quite like the fact that you used a generator approach, which guarantees that you make only on pass over the string, this seems like the perfect place for a regular expression. Some quick googling finds [this rather simple function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176023/4042267):

```
import re

def convert(name):
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

This is definitely shorter, even though that cryptic regex is not very easy to understand. But following your code, while written quite straightforward, is also not easy, especially with the deep nesting.

It works by first splitting runs of upper-case letters followed by one or more lowercase letters so that the last upper-case letter goes to the lower-case letter run. So `"ABCdef"` becomes `"AB_Cdef"`.

Then it separates runs of not-upper-case letters, followed by a single upper-case letter with a `"_"`, so `"abcD"` becomes `"abc_D"`.

To get a bit more performance out of this, you should pre-compile the regexes:

```
first_cap_re = re.compile('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)')
all_cap_re = re.compile('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])')
def convert(name):
    s1 = first_cap_re.sub(r'\1_\2', name)
    return all_cap_re.sub(r'\1_\2', s1).lower()
```

---

Performance wise, all algorithms are similar:

[image]

Not quite surprising, they all give a linear behavior (as a function of string length).

My regex version needs to make two passes over the string and is therefore consistently slower. The function written by [@Ev.Kounis in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185974/98493) outperforms both of ours, but the [regex approach by @Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185982/98493) is even faster, because it manages to do only one pass, but with a regex.

Note that all functions are very fast, so as long as you need this less than a few thousand times per second, any is fine.

---

The test strings were generated with this code:

```
import random
import string

strings = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(n))
           for n in range(10, 2000, 20)]
```

In Python 3 it could have been:

```
strings = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=k))
           for k in range(10, 2000, 20)]
```

Comment: I have the feeling that I would love this answer if I understood `regex`. My mind is too small for it though. +1

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I totally agree (since I did not come up with it myself, see the link for the source). Here is at least some explanation: The first substitution takes care of continuous runs of caps (so it splits of the last capital letter from a run of capital letters), while the last substitution splits runs of lower case letters followed by an upper case letter.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful analysis and performance measurement. Because of the latter, I accepted @peilonrayz solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit shorter:

```
def cc2jl(s):
  return "".join(["_"+l if i and l.isupper() and not s[i-1:i+2].isupper() else l for i, l in enumerate(s)]).lower()
```

Regular Expression Alternative:

```
rx = re.compile(r"(?<=.)(((?<![A-Z])[A-Z])|([A-Z](?=[a-z])))")
def cc2jl(s):
    return rx.sub("_\\1", s).lower()
```

Comment: My observation is the fact that the code is longer than it is necessary, my answer is the alternate solution. Readability is subjective, compared to regex I think it is easier to read.

Comment: @Graipher fixed

Comment: Added your function to the timings

Comment: "_(...) compared to regex I think it is easier to read_". Nope

Comment: Thanks @Graipher, I've revised that code and added a regex alternative also